# How do you open a app in Safari that has 2 words in the name?

Tags: ios, safari

My problem is that I want to be able to open a app through Safari but I'm not sure how to do that with a app that has two words in the app name.

For example I know that if I want to open a app in Safari (Lets say Youtube) that I would put
"Youtube://" in the address bar and it would take me to the Youtube app. But my problem is that I don't know how to open a app if it has two words in the name of the app. For example if I wanted to open Game Center I don't know how I would do that because putting in to the address bar "Game Center://" doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can only open apps that have registered their custom URL scheme. This has nothing to do with app name (it might coincidentally be the same). You can unzip the .ipa file of an app from AppStore on your computer, look for Info.plist file and see if it has any URL schemes. If it does, you can open that app. If not, sorry.

Comment: Here's a list of tons of supported URL schemes: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes